# Problem with CSS Isolation when I use AddRazorRuntimeCompilation

Tags: razor-pages, .net-6.0, runtime-compilation

I use CSS Isolation, but when I use `builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();` CSS Isolation not works.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/WebApplication1.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
```

All styles will be loaded, but not afford to my elements.

```
h1[b-2uayqwgjuo]{
    color:red;
}
/* _content/WebApplication1/Pages/Privacy.cshtml.rz.scp.css */
h1[b-5u69ocmej3]{
    color:blue;
}
```

How can I handle that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use, `::deep`
for example

```
<div>
    <input id="first-name-input" type="text" />
</div>
```

If you want to set style to `first-name-input` you have to do like this:

```
::deep #first-name-input {
    background: red;
}
```

Summary: If any elements doesn't have random element like `5u69ocmej3` you have to set style for those like above codes.

Comment: ::deep doesnt seem to be a valid css pseudo selector - when I try to use it, I get a compiler error saying 'unknown pseudo selector 'deep'