# why CSS isolation disable when add RazorRuntimeCompilation in .net 6

Tags: .net, .net-6.0

I create new .net 6 web application and CSS isolation work fine but when I add this line of code `builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();` to my Program.cs all CSS isolation styles will disable automatically. **What should I do?** I found this post [Problem with CSS Isolation when I use AddRazorRuntimeCompilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69953581) but it not work for me.

Comment: This post has a proper explanation and a working solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70257443/adding-addrazorruntimecompilation-to-the-container-in-net-core-6-will-break-t